# Did not find why angular2 component not able to bind foundation modal on revisiting the tab

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I have a parent component which calls another component which renders the modal on the same page. On first load parent component is able to pass the data to child component. but once i go to another page and comes back then data from parent is not getting bound to child components modal.

Steps to follow in plunker:-

1. Enter any value in 1st input box(abcd)
2. Enter modal1 in 2nd textbox
3. click on modal1 button
4. correct value in modal will apeear
5. change value in 1st textbox to abcdef
6. change second text box value to modal2
7. click on modal2 button
8. correct value will come
9. now rechange value in first textbox to abcedfghij
10. change value to modal1 in 1st textbox
11. click on modal1
12. value not getting updated. It should get updated as binding is on the same field and passed to both components.

Plunker:- https://plnkr.co/edit/GNPyL6DzzxCzUD8VZMRF?p=preview

```
    {
    import {Component,AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core'        
    @Component({
      selector: 'revel2',
      inputs: ['value']
      template: `
      <div id="myModal2" class="small reveal" data-reveal  aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
    I am Modal2 and I got value from parent component as:-
    {{value}}
    </div>`

    })
    export class ModalComponent2  {
      value:string;
      ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        $('#myModal2').foundation();
        $(window).trigger('open.fndtn.reveal');
      }

    }
    }
```

Comment: You should avoid using angular + jquery (because of conflicts). I recomand a foundation angular intergration like https://circlingthesun.github.io/angular-foundation-6/

Comment: The one you mentioned here is for angular 1.x versions or does it support angular2.x versions too. Also my complete application is using foundation-6, so switiching now will be a big piece of work.

Comment: Just re that jQuery comment, if I am going to use jQuery, then I install the jQuery package and then inside the specific component's I am going to use jQuery in,... `let $ = require ("jQuery");` It's not a huge deal if this is done in multiple components either as it just gets pulled from cache thereafter.

Comment: So you mean if i use jQuery in your said way, it will work correctly?